# Do the rewards of custom contract size in OTC derivatives justify the counterparty risk?

Tags: derivatives, risk-management, pink-sheets

If I decide to trade OTC derivatives, I take on counterparty risk. Since the transaction is not overseen by a clearing house/firm, I accept the risk that the counterparty may not honour the obligation.

What is the 'extra' reward that I get for taking the 'extra' risk? Just the fact that the lot size is customizable (i.e less than 100 shares/lot)? Just wondering if there are other rewards because this clearly does not justify the risk

Comment: Because there is no listed equivalent to the OTC product you are trading?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: For example you may want an option with a strike that is not listed, or an option on a basket of stocks or some other "exotic" underlying, or a FX Forward without liquid future equivalent, or an equity swap without equivalent listed CFD etc...